# can you help me simplify this RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Like most coders I like to take the shortest and most simple route when coding something, and mod_rewrites are no exception. I was just wondering if there is anyway to simplify this code so that I can add onto it easier.

```
RewriteRule ^giving-tree/([0-9+]?)/?$ giving-tree.php?ageBegin=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^giving-tree/([0-9+]?)/([0-9+]?)/?$ giving-tree.php?ageBegin=$1&ageEnd=$2 [nc]
RewriteRule ^giving-tree/([0-9+]?)/([0-9+]?)/([0-9+]?)/?$ giving-tree.php?ageBegin=$1&ageEnd=$2&page=$3 [nc]
```

Basically I just need to be able to define certain parts as optional.... I don't know if it's possible, but I could sure use help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, but you can simplify the rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^giving-tree/ giving-tree.php
```

And then parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in `giving-tree.php`. Here's a simple version:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($parts[1]){
  $ageBegin = $parts[1];
}
if(isset($parts[2]){
  $ageEnd = $parts[2];
}
if(isset($parts[3]){
  $page = $parts[3];
}
```